# Why do stat_poly_eq and lm differ in their estimation of r2

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, lm

I'm trying to work out how good my regression model is. I've got some data like this:

```
data <- structure(list(standard_conc_ngul = c(50, 50, 50, 5, 5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.05, 0.05, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005), ct = c(18.3305377960205, 
18.133768081665, 17.8813705444336, 21.5002365112305, 21.4915542602539, 
22.7616996765137, 23.6836719512939, 25.3699340820312, 25.3488445281982, 
28.984302520752, 26.7397594451904, 27.8844776153564)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> print(data)
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   standard_conc_ngul    ct
                <dbl> <dbl>
 1             50      18.3
 2             50      18.1
 3             50      17.9
 4              5      21.5
 5              5      21.5
 6              0.5    22.8
 7              0.5    23.7
 8              0.05   25.4
 9              0.05   25.3
10              0.005  29.0
11              0.005  26.7
12              0.005  27.9
```

When I model with `lm`, I get an r2 of 0.692817

```
> model <- lm(ct ~ standard_conc_ngul, data = data)
> summary(model)$r.squared
[1] 0.692817
```

But when I use `stat_poly_eq` on a plot, the r2 is 0.973. Very different!

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = standard_conc_ngul, y = ct)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans="log2") +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x,
               aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), after_stat(rr.label), sep = "~~~")),
               parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 3, f.digits = 3, p.digits = 3, 
               rr.digits = 3)
```

[image]

I can't work out why it's different! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove your `log` scale, you will have the same output:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

ggplot(data, aes(x = standard_conc_ngul, y = ct)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x) +
  #scale_x_continuous(trans="log2") +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x,
               aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), after_stat(rr.label), sep = "~~~")),
               parse = TRUE, coef.digits = 3, f.digits = 3, p.digits = 3, 
               rr.digits = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I thought the log scale just affected the scaling of the image, not the fit. How would I include a log function in my `lm` to match the r2=0.973 achieved in the log scaled plot?

Comment: @Mike `lm(ct ~ log(standard_conc_ngul), data = data)`

Comment: Great thanks. Is there a way to log scale the x-axis, but not affect the lm fit on the plot?